# Как организовать чтение файла

Tags: файлы, c++

Есть ли какая-нибудь библиотека, которая добавляет функцию, которая позволяет читать файл, который находится в интернете.

Например, функция file("http://mysite.com/file.txt") должна возвращать содержимое файла fie.txt.

Есть ли такая библиотека, которая сможет это реализовать?

Comment: Например, [cUrl][1]


  [1]: http://curl.haxx.se

Comment: [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/cplusplus/)?

Comment: А почему бы не сохранять сначала его на диске, а потом стандартно не читать файл? или какая то специфика?
Просто открытие файла возвращает дескриптор файла, системный вызов. А что будет возвращать сетевая функция не понятно

Comment: не хотелось бы создавать лишние файлы. И делать возможным чтение их пользователем тоже не желательно

Comment: возможно libcurl и подходит, но чтобы прочитать файл там нужно явно больше одной функции

Comment: Если одной, то попробуйте `system("wget ....")` или `popen("wget ...", "r")`,

однако, если строка не константная, то все равно что-то придется написать, чтобы ее сформировать.

Comment: спасибо всем, кто помог

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Есть](http://www.cyberforum.ru/blogs/131347/blog1151.html#a_7)

Comment: Интересно, зачем в этом примере писать обертку для `fwrite()` с точно такой же сигнатурой?

Answer (score 0):

Если язык не принципиален, то в с# есть очень удобные средства для этого. Приведу пример метода, который сохраняет страничку в текстовый файл:

```
public void DownloadInfo(string fileName, string url)
    {
        // Create a request for the URL. 
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        // If required by the server, set the credentials.
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        // Get the response.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        // Display the status.
        Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
        // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        // Display the content.
        //Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, responseFromServer);
        // Clean up the streams and the response.
        reader.Close();
        response.Close();
    }
```

Используйте для работы данного кода пространства имён:

```
using System; 
using System.IO; //Работа с файлами
using System.Net; //Обеспечение работы с web-страницей
```

А вот тут для с++, eсли что:
     [Разработка web-приложений на C++](http://habrahabr.ru/post/61563/);
     [Создание веб-приложений на Visual C++](http://www.devels.ru/?what=art&p=485)

Comment: @Kristya: Если уж пользоваться мощью .NET, то достаточно простого

    var stream = new WebClient().OpenRead(url);

Или если надо в файл,

    new WebClient().DownloadFile(url, filename);

Comment: @VladD, спасибо))) буду знать) Почти всегда есть разные способы решения, просто нужно выбирать подходящий в зависимости от ситуации)))